# Is there a sefer that is m'laket all of the sources from Chazal relating to marriage?

Tags: jewish-books, marriage

I have read several different sefarim that are related to marriage - Binyan Bayis, the new sefer by Rabbi Schaeffer, the kuntris from R Wolbe - but is there a sefer that has all of the midrashim, sugyas in shas, braisas, etc and puts them all in one place? I know they have this type of thing for different inyanim.

Thanks

Comment: What are you defining as "relating to marriage"? I mean, there's a whole sixth of the Mishnah labelled "Nashim", I have a couple seforim that contain all of that plus Nezikin in one book, but I suspect that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: חופת חתנים quotes a lot of sources

Comment: @Salmononius2 thanks for the clarification question. I am referring to the agadatas in Shas, the different midrashim - everything discussing the "values" and the "inyanim" of marriage, not the straight halacha. Like you said - for that, we have the Mishnayos in seder nashim (and the Gemara)

Comment: There are sefarim that do this on a wide variety of topics. See Sefer HaAggadah for example.